# jQuery - Only carry out action if url doesn't contain any parametres

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs only if an attribute is blank:

```
if (!$(".main-image").attr("src")) {
    loadImageAjax();
}
```

But I also only want it to run IF the url doesn't contain any parametres.

So only if the domain is simply: www.domain.com and not www.domain.com/?image=33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the existence of the `?` character. More often than not, if there are going to be url parameters, the `?` character will also exist.

```
if ( url.indexOf("?") < 0 ) {
   // code for 'no parameters' goes here
}
```

If your URLs use a different pattern you will need a function that knows how to check where the parameters are. (Stack Overflow URLs are an example of URLs that do not follow the `?a=1&b=2` pattern).

If you want to disallow everything that is not "www.domain.com", you can check for the existence of the "/" character.

```
var indexOfSlash = url.indexOf("/");

// the second check is just in case you want to allow "www.domain.com/"
if ( indexOfSlash < 0 || !url.substring(indexOfSlash + 1) ) {
   // code for 'no parameters' goes here
}
```